# Identify LEGO set. Star Wars?

Tags: set-identification

Trying to figure out what this set is from a large bin I bought.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from  [Set # 75076-1: Republic Gunship](https://brickset.com/sets/75076-1/Republic-Gunship)

[image]

Keypart : [Cone 2 x 2 x 2 - Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3942c&idColor=59#T=C&C=59) in Dark Red

Comment: Thank you.  I was thinking gunship but searches kept showing the big kit.  Appreciate your help - am new to this side of LEGO - id’ing sets, parts, etc.